# Translating French paper into English

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, translation-request, mathematical-french

I am currently studying a French paper on Einstein manifolds by Berard Bergery and I have doubts that my translation of the following sentence is correct:

> De plus, puisque $G$ agit par isometries, $M/G$ herite par quotient d'une metrique, qui est enfait une metrique riemannienne ("a bord" eventuellement).

My translation:

> Furthermore, since $G$ acts by isometries, the quotient $M/G$ inherits a metric, which is actually a Riemannian metric (possibly  (..)).

Is this correct so far? I don't know how to translate the last two words, apologies for leaving out the accents!

Comment: "Une variété à bord" translates as  "a manifold with boundary", so here we might have "a riemannian metric, possibly  with boundary". But I don't know  if such a concept exists (the standard books on differential manifolds don't seem to cover riemannian metrics on manifolds with boundary)

Comment: "À bord" is "with boundary". [Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary).

Comment: @Did: les bons esprits se rencontrent :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg En vérité. Mais votre commentaire (que je n'avais pas vu en tapant le mien) est plus complet.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg this is what confused me, too (i.e. a Riemannian metric with boundary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Furthermore, since $G$ acts by isometries, $M/G$ inherits by the quotient operation a metric, which is in fact a Riemannian metric (possibly with boundary).

Probably the last part means "the metric of a Riemannian manifold, possibly with boundary", but the French is not quite saying that.

Note that "enfait" should have been "en fait".

Comment: Yes, indeed that should have been "en fait" (I'll leave it as it is so as to not interfere indirectly with your answer). Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good except "$M/G$ hérite par quotient d'une métrique" actually means "$M/G$ inherits a metric by quotient".

"à bord eventuellement" means "possibly on the edge" but not sure of the context.

I guess you got the meaning right.

Comment: "On the edge": no.